# Publish over ssh error jenkins [Failed to connect session for config [test12]. Message [Auth fail]]

Tags: jenkins, ssh

Installed new Jenkins, want to use Publish over SSH plugin.
publish over SSH plugin version: 1.24
getting below error.

`[Failed to connect session for config [test12]. Message [Auth fail]]`

Also, tried the solution given here https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-57495?focusedCommentId=372383&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-372383

Went to my EC2 server.

`sudo su jenkins`.

under `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh`.

created keys with the following command also with `passphrase`.

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -m PEM`.

after that copied the `id_rsa.pub` to the target host.

did the `ssh -i id_rsa ubuntu@serverip` it works from the command-line.
But is broken from the UI